# How can I generate a simple river surface seen from above, in a browser game?

Tags: animation, water, non-photorealistic

I'm developing my first browser-based game, a very simple signup gamification where users become captains of boats, and their referred friends join the boats. The boats race to a finish line.

There is only one view, bird's eye, that shows the boats on a river. To simplify things further, I thought I would keep the boats fixed, and have the river flow from right to left. Here's [the Codepen](http://codepen.io/dandv/pen/aOqaMZ) I have so far:

[image]

How can I make the river animation look more immersive? I remember after playing Chronos ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umfq5JPCUtE)) or [River Raid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9uCGFfqT4mw&t=22)  back in the day for a while, when I'd move my eyes off the monitor, my vision would "flow" in the other direction for a while - that's how good the effects were.

One idea I had was to use a [perfectly looping](https://www.reddit.com/r/perfectloops/comments/3c5nq4/horizontal_river_flowing_from_right_to_left/) background GIF, so that the eye anchors on the continuously moving background, and the boats *appear* to move the opposite way.

Comment: "look more immersive" is quite based on one's opinion, I'm afraid...

Comment: Could you clarify what you're looking for in the animation? It sounds like you don't simply want "flowing water", but something in addition, and I don't understand what it is.

Comment: @Anko: I want the water to appear as flowing, and the boats to appear as going upstream, even though they stay (relatively) fixed in their initial positions. I've posted an answer with what I've got working so far.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Perlin noise](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm)

A 2d Perlin noise , with an appropriate color gradient, to simulate river surface:

[image]

Two 1d Perlin noise for the two river margins:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for the brain to perceive the illusion that the ships are moving in the opposite direction to the one in which the background flows, the eyes need to anchor on the background. In my first experiment, the waves were thin lines, and didn't provide much of a *unified* background; the anchor was the boats.

Below is an experiment that simply pans a water texture using CSS keyframes ([very CPU-intensive on Chrome unless you force GPU rasterization](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=507015)). You should click "Full page" and "Redraw" after running the code snippet, or you can view it [on Codepen](http://codepen.io/dandv/pen/QbmbrW).

Suggestions are welcome.

```js
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

var
  boatHeight = 40;
  boatBow = 80;

var canvas, context,
  sizeX, sizeY,

  boats = [],
  numBoats;
  minBoatLength = 140,  /* minimum boat length to accommodate the text */
  maxBoatLength = minBoatLength + 60 + boatBow;
  
var runAnimationCheckbox, numBoatsControl;

function Boat(x, y, length, text) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.length = length;
  this.text = text;
  this.color = '#4F5E5B';
  return this;
}

Boat.prototype.draw = function () {
  // add a shadow to boats so they look more realistic, though in reality there wouldn't be much of a shadow
  context.shadowOffsetX = 2;
  context.shadowOffsetY = 2;
  context.shadowBlur = 5;
  context.shadowColor = 'black';

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
  context.lineTo(this.x + this.length, this.y);
  context.quadraticCurveTo(this.x + this.length + 15, this.y/* control point */, this.x + this.length + boatBow, this.y + boatHeight / 2/* bow */);
  context.quadraticCurveTo(this.x + this.length + 15, this.y + boatHeight/* control point */, this.x + this.length, this.y + boatHeight/* back from bow */);
  context.lineTo(this.x, this.y + boatHeight);
  context.fillStyle = this.color;
  context.fill();

  // add the text, without shadows
  context.font = '16pt Calibri';
  context.fillStyle = '#000';
  context.shadowOffsetX = context.shadowOffsetY = context.shadowBlur = 0;
  context.fillText(this.text, this.x + 10, this.y + 26);

};


Boat.random = function createRandomBoat(b) {
  return new Boat(
    Math.random() * (sizeX - maxBoatLength - 20),
    // 0, 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4
    -boatHeight / 4 + sizeY / 2 /* center boat generation at half river width */ + (sizeY - boatHeight) / numBoats /* size of a boat channel */ * (Math.floor(b/2)*(b%2?1:-1)),
    minBoatLength + Math.random() * (maxBoatLength - minBoatLength),
    'Student from ...'
  );
}  

function createBoats() {
  for (var b = 1; b <= numBoats; b++) {
    boats.push(Boat.random(b));
  }
  // Make the first boat "you"
  boats[0].text = 'You are here';
  boats[0].color = '#A7C8B2';
}

function clearCanvas() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, sizeX, sizeY);
}

function drawBoats() {
  for (i = 0; i < boats.length; i++) {
    boats[i].draw();
  }
}

function animate(timestamp) {
  clearCanvas();
  drawBoats();
  // keep animating
  if (runAnimationCheckbox.checked)
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};

// automatically resize the canvas to fill its container
function resizeCanvas() {
  sizeX = canvas.width = canvas.scrollWidth;
  sizeY = canvas.height = canvas.scrollHeight;
  console.log('Resized to', sizeX, sizeY);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

  runAnimationCheckbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
  canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  numBoatsControl = document.querySelector('input[type="number"]');
  numBoats = numBoatsControl.value;

  runAnimationCheckbox.onchange = function (event) {
    if (this.checked) animate();
  };
  
  numBoatsControl.onchange = document.querySelector('button').onclick = function (event) {
    boats = [];
    numBoats = numBoatsControl.value;
    createBoats();
    clearCanvas();
    drawBoats();
  };

  document.querySelector('#background').onchange = function (event) {
    var urlString = 'url(' + this.value + ')';
    document.querySelector('canvas').style.backgroundImage = urlString;
  };

  document.querySelector('select').onchange = function (event) {
    var urlString = 'url(' + this.value + ')';
    document.querySelector('canvas').style.backgroundImage = urlString;
  };

  setTimeout(function () {
    resizeCanvas();
    createBoats();
    drawBoats();
    animate();
  
  }, 100);  // give the canvas a chance to be sized, otherwise we'll get the default 300x150 dimensions

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
/*  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/1iQw8zz.jpg') no-repeat center center;*/
  line-height: 1.5em;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

canvas#river {
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  background: url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-9F5e4P9JxwE/UlAYhVwdWUI/AAAAAAAACYI/1VlbEE5O0aI/s400/Water_WaveAnimation_16frames_SeamlessTest.gif') repeat;
  background-size: 400px auto;
  
  animation: animatedBackground 5s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 5s linear infinite;
  
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);  /* doesn't actually force GPU rasterization */
}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    100% { background-position: -400px 0; }
}

/* for Opera, Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    100% { background-position: -400px 0; }
}
```

```html
<p>
Enter background URL: <input type="text" id="background" size=100>
<br>Or try one of these:
<select>
  <option>[default]</option>
  <option value="http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/perforated_white_leather.png">Subtle pattern: perforated white leater</option>
  <option value="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-OtKPPI6BPm8/Uk_wRVK8rmI/AAAAAAAACUk/ZvzC-lWuB_E/s640/AnimatedWater_004.png">http://auryn-beorn.blogspot.com/2013/10/creator-resource-animated-water-texture.html #2</option>
  <option value="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-S_9dNop-3V0/Uk_2YlzXBDI/AAAAAAAACU8/oo4F2FJpo-4/s640/AnimatedWater_005.png">http://auryn-beorn.blogspot.com/2013/10/creator-resource-animated-water-texture.html #3</option>
  <option value="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-wR-RuA5QUwY/Uk_2eXBjxxI/AAAAAAAACVE/0dVYl1g2EuQ/s640/AnimatedWater_006.png">http://auryn-beorn.blogspot.com/2013/10/creator-resource-animated-water-texture.html #4</option>
  <option value="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-bYhE5gQ-wqo/Uk_2jmBprsI/AAAAAAAACVM/fwFjFdZ5VyI/s640/AnimatedWater_007.png">http://auryn-beorn.blogspot.com/2013/10/creator-resource-animated-water-texture.html #5</option>
  <option value="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-luyCsWFRkpc/Uk_2raLOg-I/AAAAAAAACVU/Sgz6k58BUco/s640/AnimatedWater_008.png">http://auryn-beorn.blogspot.com/2013/10/creator-resource-animated-water-texture.html #6</option>
  <option value="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-IFmfJ19lZkw/Uk_6N6wNjNI/AAAAAAAACV8/OFQ1BOp1Ins/s640/AnimatedWater_012.png">http://auryn-beorn.blogspot.com/2013/10/creator-resource-animated-water-texture.html #7 - seamless</option>
  <option value="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-5k_7_FEdMrQ/UlAXnsxGHCI/AAAAAAAACYA/UuXkei0lRDM/s400/Water_WaveAnimation_16frames_TestRippling_6_Smear.gif">http://auryn-beorn.blogspot.com/2013/10/creator-resource-animated-water-texture.html #8</option>
  <option value="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-MwXleupp6FM/UHU5pF4jYjI/AAAAAAAADcA/OXjgoPBpy8Y/s1600/Tileable+classic+water+texture.jpg">http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-MwXleupp6FM/UHU5pF4jYjI/AAAAAAAADcA/OXjgoPBpy8Y/s1600/Tileable+classic+water+texture.jpg</option>
  <option value="http://i.imgur.com/yk2LLAg.gif">30000fps</option>
  <option value="http://media.giphy.com/media/McFOLsoTLoudi/giphy.gif">http://giphy.com/gifs/mr-gif-mrgif-patterns-McFOLsoTLoudi</option>
  <option value="http://i.imgur.com/wnbZg44.gif">http://imgur.com/gallery/BjSEE/ (Honeycomb)</option>
  <option value="http://i.imgur.com/H4JyDWw.gif">http://mr-gif.com/post/14532187128</option>
  <option value="http://i.imgur.com/CFO1StD.gif">http://30000fps.com/post/107836389508</option>
  <option value="http://i.imgur.com/V6Z7K2J.gif">http://60000fps.tumblr.com/post/114106084470</option>
  <option value="http://i.imgur.com/I0ES1Lc.gif">http://30000fps.com/post/118219650398</option>
  <option value="http://i.imgur.com/Z56ICih.gif">http://30000fps.com/post/117644318763</option>
  <option value="http://i.imgur.com/EBGBPTe.gif">http://30000fps.com/post/122047609773</option>
  <option value="http://i.imgur.com/CAm1A4X.gif">http://30000fps.com/post/108557720353</option>
  <option value="http://media.giphy.com/media/ToMjGpANd3KoRiE4ZYA/giphy.gif">http://giphy.com/gifs/sebasandclim-ToMjGpANd3KoRiE4ZYA</option>
  <option value="http://media.giphy.com/media/3o85xEIe1YKaGrSvhC/giphy.gif">http://giphy.com/gifs/gfaught-loop-colors-3o85xEIe1YKaGrSvhC</option>
  <option>http://i.imgur.com/A1nDSdr.gif</option>
  <option>http://33.media.tumblr.com/743b05ff21fde73a5a018c5506278cc3/tumblr_nj84h6W95C1s4fz4bo1_500.gif</option>
  <option>http://33.media.tumblr.com/23e95fd77d71f41d72be5ca3eb7719a7/tumblr_nof002o30r1s4fz4bo1_r6_500.gif</option>
  <option>http://38.media.tumblr.com/a66a4fd09436ee4026b0b952a185c2da/tumblr_nnw73kScuN1s4fz4bo1_500.gif</option>
  <option>http://i.imgur.com/HwfZ77H.gif</option>
  <option>http://i.imgur.com/ISheC3U.gif</option>
  <option value="http://i.imgur.com/N6miqht.gif">http://30000fps.com/post/108466273273</option>
</select> (WARNING: some may take time to load! Go back through the list after you've seen all patterns)
  <br/>Find more at <a href="http://subtlepatterns.com/">Subtle patterns</a> or <a href="http://giphy.com/search/pattern">Giphy /pattern</a>.
</p>
  
<canvas id="river"></canvas>
<div id="river-controls">
  <button>Redraw </button><input type="number" value="5" style="width: 2rem"> boats
  <span hidden><input type="checkbox" checked>Animate</span>
</div>
```